# Points inside polygon in PostGIS

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I have a table samplecol that contains (a sample):

```
vessel_hash  | status | station | speed |  latitude   |  longitude  | course | heading |        timestamp         |                      the_geom                      
--------------+--------+---------+-------+-------------+-------------+--------+---------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 5     | -5.41844510 | 36.12160900 | 314    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:31:04.000Z | 0101000020E61000001BF33AE2900F424090AF4EDF7CAC15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 3008    | 0     | -5.41778710 | 36.12144900 | 117    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:43:27.000Z | 0101000020E6100000E2900DA48B0F424042C3AC61D0AB15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 17    | -5.42236900 | 36.12356900 | 259    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:50:27.000Z | 0101000020E610000054E6E61BD10F42407C60C77F81B015C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 17    | -5.41781710 | 36.12147900 | 230    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:27:03.000Z | 0101000020E61000004D13B69F8C0F424097D6F03ED8AB15C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 61    | -5.42201900 | 36.13256100 | 157    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:08:04.000Z | 0101000020E6100000CFDC43C2F71042409929ADBF25B015C0
 103079215239 | 99     | 841     | 9     | -5.41834020 | 36.12225000 | 359    | 511     | 2016-06-12T06:33:03.000Z | 0101000020E6100000CFF753E3A50F42408D68965F61AC15C0
```

I try to fetch all points inside polygon with:

```
poisInpolygon = """SELECT col.vessel_hash,col.longitude,col.latitude,
            ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,-15.2050781 47.5172007,-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836,-15.0292969 47.6357836))'),
            ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom)) FROM samplecol As col;"""
```

The output is:

```
(103079215291L, Decimal('40.87123100'), Decimal('29.24107000'), False) 

(103079215291L, Decimal('40.86702000'), Decimal('29.23967000'), False) 

(103079215291L, Decimal('40.87208200'), Decimal('29.22113000'), False) 

(103079215291L, Decimal('40.86973200'), Decimal('29.23963000'), False) 

(103079215291L, Decimal('40.87770800'), Decimal('29.20229900'), False)
```

I don't figure out what is False in the results. Is this the correct way or am I doing something wrong?

Also this code uses the INDEX in the field `the_geom`?

Comment: Why are there `latitude` and `longitude` in the table? Should `the_geom` be the corresponding `Point` to them? Then this table isn't properly normalized and that might be a part of your problem.

Comment: So you mean that latitude longitude must not be on table? The function to find all points in polygon that I create is wrong?

Comment: If `the_geom` is the actual point, lat and lon is already in there (use `st_x` and/or `st_y` to get them). When you have them additionally in the table, it might be, that the lat and/or lon of `the_geom` is different, to the ones in the other columns. And that might give you a result, that doesn't look right, because you're looking at coordinates that actually weren't used. But you didn't answer if there was such a relation between the columns.

Comment: The connection is: UPDATE samplecol
SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')',4326);

Comment: Then `longitude` and `latitude` are redundant. Only save the `Point`.

Comment: So the table will only have the point(the_geom) instead of lat lon. The function that I use is correct? Also with this func the index on geim is used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query returns `false` because all points from your sample are outside of the given polygon. Here an overview of your points (somewhere in the northeast of Tanzania) and polygon (south Europe and north Africa):

[image]

To test your query, I added another point somewhere in [`Málaga`](https://tools.wmflabs.org/geohack/geohack.php?pagename=M%C3%A1laga&language=de&params=36.72_N_4.42_W_dim:20000_region:ES-AN_type:city), which is inside of your polygon, and it returned `true` just as expected (last geometry in the insert statement as EWKT). This is the script:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (the_geom GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('0101000020E61000001BF33AE2900F424090AF4EDF7CAC15C0'),
             ('0101000020E6100000E2900DA48B0F424042C3AC61D0AB15C0'),
             ('0101000020E610000054E6E61BD10F42407C60C77F81B015C0'),
             ('0101000020E61000004D13B69F8C0F424097D6F03ED8AB15C0'),
             ('0101000020E6100000CFDC43C2F71042409929ADBF25B015C0'),
             ('0101000020E6100000CFF753E3A50F42408D68965F61AC15C0'),
             (ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POINT(-4.4427 36.7233)'));
```

And here is your query:

```
db=# SELECT 
ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,-15.2050781 47.5172007,-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836,-15.0292969 47.6357836))'),
            ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom)) 
FROM t As col;

st_contains 
-------------
 f
 f
 f
 f
 f
 f
 t
(7 Zeilen)
```

Btw: storing the same coordinates as `GEOMETRY` and as `NUMERIC` is totally redundant. You might want to get rid of the columns `latitude` and `longitude` and extract their values with [`ST_X`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html) and [`ST_Y`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html) on demand.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and inform you.

Comment: The following thought just occurred to me: make sure that you're _not_ misplacing the coordinate pairs. WGS84 requires _longitude, latitude_, not _latitude,longitude_. The latter would be inside of your polygon.

Comment: I have done this: UPDATE samplecol SET the_geom = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || longitude || ' ' || latitude || ')',4326); , so I have longitute first and latitude second. So I am ok I think? Is this right? Also I have another question. I fix my polygon and now the code returns all "t". I dont understand how can I take the real coordinates. Can you provide a solution please? Thank you

Comment: q1) I recommend you use the built-in postgis functions to create points, such as: `SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(-4.4427,36.7233),4326);` (the same point in Malaga), so that you can be sure that the result is exactly what other functions would expect. q2) If the function is returning `true` it means that all points are inside the given polygon. Can you share the _fixed_ polygon for me to take a look?

Comment: Also if I want in the query to fetch also the vessel_hash can I achieve this in single query?

Comment: I use this polygon: ((-28.828125 65.0721301,-28.125 64.7741253,-139.5703125 -47.0401821,127.265625 -44.5904672,90 71.1877539,-28.828125 65.0721301)). The question is if I can return the real coordinates from your query.

Comment: q3) just place the column name right after the `SELECT` as you were doing before: `SELECT col.vessel_hash,col.longitude,col.latitude,
            ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326; POLYGON((-15.0292969 47.6357836,-15.2050781 47.5172007,-16.2597656 29.3821751, 35.0683594 26.1159859, 38.0566406 47.6357836,-15.0292969 47.6357836))'),
            ST_GeomFromEWKT(col.the_geom)) FROM samplecol As col`